# Не тянется AttachedProperty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть AttachedProperty, содержащее URI картинки. Вот стиль для его использования на контроле (почему то не работает)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dxe:ButtonInfo}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Margin="3,0" Width="20" Height="10" Stretch="Fill"
                       Source="{Binding Path=(attached:ImageProperties.Image), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}">
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(attached:ImageProperties.Image), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue='Q'}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="GlyphKind" Value="Custom" />
</Style>
```

Текстовое поле я прикрутил для того, чтобы было видно, что это не ошибка привязки, а значение Null в свойстве.

Я не могу понять в чем тут дело, учитывая, что для обычного Button это работает. Биндинг для картинки там такой же.

Если в стиле в Image.Source подставляю URI конкретной картинки, она отображается

**UPD:**

А нет, я ошибся. В стиле для Button сделано немного иначе

```
Source="{Binding Path=(attached:ImageProperties.Image), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
```

Но когда я делаю так же для `dxe:ButtonInfo`, получаю в Output Window ошибку

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ButtonInfo', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=(0); DataItem=null; target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

Короче ошибка биндинга... Ну и, соответственно, картинки не отображаются

Comment: Удалите этот вопрос, раз уж создали отдельный

Comment: @ixSci, Не удалю, это другой вопрос. См UPD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хитробокий DevExpress в очередной раз удивил своей кривой внутренней структурой. При помощи Snoop нашел решение и исправил ContentTemplate в стиле на

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Image Margin="3,0" Width="20" DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}"
           Source="{Binding Path=(attached:ImageProperties.Image)}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Наверное, они добавили этим какую то гибкость, но это совсем не очевидно и без скальпеля не разобраться :(